# Linq To Entities question

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table called `TableA` whch has a foreign key from `TableB` and a one to many relationship to `TableB`

I want to do:

```
var v = Context.TableASet
               .Include("TableB")
               .Where(x => x.TableB.Col1 == 123)
```

But when I do `x.TableB.` I don't have the `Col1` option. this is because `TableB` has a one to many relationship so I get the properties of a collection and not a `TableB` object

What can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Any() method on TableB:

```
var v = Context.TableASet.Include("TableB").Where(x => x.TableB.Any(b => b.Col1 == 123));
```